# Chained promises in Angular. Wrong input parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have problems with chained promises.

1. I mocked backend to simulate ajax requests.

   ```
   $httpBackend.whenGET('/contacts').respond(function(method,url,data) {
       console.log("Getting contacts");

   return [200, contacts, {}];
   });
   ```
2. In my service *ContactsService* I make this ajax call and chain a handler to extract from the data (which is array of contacts) contact with some index.

   ```
   self.getContact = function(index) {
           var handler = new self.ResultHandler(index, self.handleContactSuccess);
           return $http.get("/contacts").then(handler.handleResult, self.handleError);
   }

   self.handleContactSuccess = function( response ) {
           var resultHandler = this;
           var index = resultHandler.getAdditionalData();

           if (index < response.data.length) {
               return( response.data[index]);
           } else {
               return( null );
           }
   }
   ```
3. From service I return promise
4. Then in my *ContactController* I chain one more handler to set this value into the scope.

   ```
   ContactsService.getContact(index).then(function(data) {
       console.log("Data in ContactController: " + data);
       if (data) {
           $scope.contact = data;
       } else {
           console.log("No such index");
       }
   });
   ```

   But in last handler (where I set result to scope) the data object in undefined, even though, I return object from handler in service.

So what is wrong with my code - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hq1jghyL/1/)?
Thank you.

Thank you.

Comment: Your code is very complicated. Why all the `handler`s and managers? It looks like all you need is a `$http.get(...).then(function(){...})` - the added complexity isn't worth it imo. Another tip - you can use `,` in console.log and get better results so `console.log("a"+b)` is better as `console.log("a",b)` if you want to see objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're not delegating properly. Promises rely on *return values*. You follow this correctly most of the time but when you're trying to apply delegation you're missing a return:

```
self.handleResult = function (data) {
    handleResultFunc.call(self, data);
};
```

This in promises means "return undefined immediately" since JavaScript has implicit `undefined` returns. Instead, you should `return` the result:

```
self.handleResult = function (data) {
    return handleResultFunc.call(self, data);
};
```

Overall - I think you could have avoided the issue had you used a simpler structure in your code - but I'm probably not aware of the broader design constraints you have. As an alternative - you could have referenced `self` via closure and simply do `self.handleResult = handleResultFunc` which would have been simpler as well.

Happy coding.

Comment: This construction really looks not pretty, but I need it to pass additional parameters to resultHandler. Thank you for your answer, it was really stupid mistake.